# What should be the file path pattern to use for ant, to select all the content files of an unknown subfolder name

Tags: java, file, ant, filepath

I have the following Hierarchy:

> MyFolder -> MySubFolder (Dynamic name) - > filesToCopy

I need to copy them to a path like:

> MyNewFolder -> filesToCopy

Please notice that i have no idea what is the name of MySubFolder.

The pattern i tried to use in ant is:

```
MyNewFolder/**/*
```

This didn't work, anyone knows what should i write?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

The [flatten mapper](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html) enables you to do this. Use it with the copy or move tasks.

## Example

```
├── build.xml
├── myfolder
│   ├── one
│   │   ├── file1.txt
│   │   ├── file2.txt
│   │   └── file3.txt
│   ├── three
│   │   └── file6.txt
│   └── two
│       ├── file4.txt
│       └── file5.txt
└── mynewfolder
    ├── file1.txt
    ├── file2.txt
    ├── file3.txt
    ├── file4.txt
    ├── file5.txt
    └── file6.txt
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="build">

  <target name="build">
    <copy todir="mynewfolder">
      <fileset dir="myfolder">
        <include name="**/*.txt"/>
      </fileset>
      <mapper type="flatten"/>
    </copy>
  </target>

</project>
```